# RSpec - Mock ampersand-symbol parameters

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I have the following code

```
def foo(bar)
  bar.map(&:to_sym)
end
```

I want to set expectation to `map` with `&:to_sym`. If I do

```
describe '#foo' do
  it 'should convert to array of symbols' do
    bar = %w(test1 test2)
    bar.should_receive(:map).with(&:to_sym)
    foo(bar)
  end
end
```

It fails with

```
ArgumentError: no receiver given
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the question. Finally, I came to the following code. It doesn't set expectations for `#map` but makes sure each element of array is converted to symbol:

```
def foo(bar)
  bar.map(&:to_sym)
end

describe '#foo' do
  it 'should convert to array of symbols' do
    bar = %w(test1 test2)
    bar.each do |i|
      sym = i.to_sym
      i.should_receive(:to_sym).and_return(sym)
    end
    foo(bar)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I understand better now what's going on. 
This bit of code is doing a lot more than just sending an object to a method.

```
bar.map(&:to_sym)
```

"The map method, from the module Enumerable that is “mixed in” to the Array class, invokes a block argument once for each element of self, in this case the array, and returns a new array containing the values returned by the block. However in this case, we don’t have a block, we have &:capitalize.....When a unary ampersand is prepended to an object in Ruby, if the object is not a Proc object, the interpreter attempts to convert the object to a proc by calling to_proc on it. Since :capitalize is a Symbol, not a Proc, Ruby goes along and sends the to_proc message to :capitalize,.." http://swaggadocio.com/post/287689063

http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html

Basically you're trying to verify that a block is being passed into #map which I don't believe you can do in rspec. Basically this:

```
    bar.map {|element| element.to_sym}
```

I would also say that this test is relying to much on the implementation details of #foo which tends to make the test brittle since it's common for the code inside the method to change in refactoring. Instead you should test that the correct value is being returned by the method.

```
    describe '#foo' do
      it 'should convert to array of symbols' do
        bar = %w(test1 test2)
        foo(bar).should == [:test1 , :test2]
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to figure out the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

The method #foo is expecting an argument which you did not provide

```
describe '#foo' do
  it 'should convert to array of symbols' do
    bar = %w(test1 test2)
    bar.should_receive(:map).with(&:to_sym)
    foo(bar) #change your original line to this
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a typo. However, it doesn't answer the question.